# Como redirecionar Css para apenas uma Div

Tags: css, html5

Estou criando um site no qual preciso utilizar um arquivo de css exclusivo para a a div responsável para exibir os serviços realizados nele. O problema é que esse arquivo css é baixado de outro lugar, e ele acaba alterando o restante da pagina. Alguém sabe como devo proceder nesse caso?

Comment: Alguma chance de você pegar o que é importante desses CSS e colocasse no seu site targeteando sua div? Não recomendo puxar CSSs exteriores que não sejam objetivos.

Comment: A div tem um id ou classe específica?

Comment: Já estamos fazendo isso, mas não existe um método mais fácil e simples de fazer isso do que ficar apagando e testando?

Answer (score 1):

### Copie o Código

Na minha opinião, a melhor forma seria realmente você extrair o que seria importante do código para você e depois colar no seu código adaptando o que fosse necessário para a sua div. Porém, seguem duas outras formas de fazer isso:

### IFrame

Existe a possibilidade de você criar uma página nova, digamos: `div.html` e customizar com o código de fora como se fosse uma nova página e depois simplesmente puxá-la para sua div, porque assim o CSS da página irá afetar somente o que está dentro da div e vice-versa. Seria só colocar assim na sua div:

```
<div>
    <iframe src="div.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

### Style Scoped

Essa não é exatamente uma forma ideal, já que o seu suporte hoje em dia está limitado somente para o **Firefox**, mas eu acho que merece uma menção. Existe essa maneira onde você escreve um novo estilo onde você quiser na sua página e ela se aplica somente naquela região com o `Scoped`. Dessa forma você poderia também importar esse CSS. Exemplo:

```
<div>
  <style scoped>
    h1 { color: red;   }
    p  { color: brown; }
  </style>
  <h1>Esse é um H1 afetado pelo scoped. Independente do estilo da página, ele será vermelho.</h1>
  <p>Esse é um parágrafo na scoped div. O texto será marrom.</p>
</div>

<p>Esse parágrafo não será afetado e será preto.</p>
```

Você poderia usar desta forma no seu caso:

```
<div>
    <style scoped>
        @import "externo.css";
    </style>
</div>
```

---

Fontes:

- https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped

Answer (score 0):

adicione uma class na div, exemplo

```
<div class="nomedaclasse">
```

depois em um css ou tag style, copie o código do arquivo de css que vc pegará de outro lugar, ao invés de usar o arquivo inteiro. exemplo:

```
<style>
.nomedaclasse{ background-color: #fff; } /* substitua o background-color pelo atributo desejado*/
</style>
```